# Min-Max difference in continuous part of certain length within a np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of values like this:

```
a = np.array((1, 3, 4, 5, 10))
```

In this case the array has length 5. Now I want to know the difference between the lowest and highest value in the array, but only within a certain continuous part of the array, for example with length 3.

So in this case it would be the difference between 4 and 10, so 6. It would also be nice to have the index of the starting point of the continuous part (in the above example that would be 2). So something like this:

```
def f(a, lenght_of_part):
    ...
    return (max_difference, starting index)
```

I know I could iterate over sliced parts of the array, but for my actual purpose I have ~150k arrays of length 1500, so that would take too long.

What would be an easy and quick way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit tricky to get done in a vectorised way in Numpy.  One option is to use `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`, which requires care, because it allows to access arbitrary memory.  Here's an example for a window size of `k = 3`:

```
>>> k = 3
>>> shape = (len(a) - k + 1, k)
>>> b = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
            a, shape=shape, strides=(a.itemsize, a.itemsize))
>>> moving_ptp = b.ptp(axis=1)
>>> start_index = moving_ptp.argmax()
>>> moving_ptp[start_index]
6
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Implementing it into my code as we speak!